# Lambda function using Dynamodb and SNS - timed out

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Am trying to use a DynamoDb Item value in the SNS service to send the notification. Its failing with the timeout error however fetch from Dynamodb is successful and notification is also sent. But it keep retrying and timeout after processing multiple times.

> {
>     "errorMessage": "2018-01-02T10:14:55.463Z c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds"
>   }

Now, I also tried using the parameter `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` but dint help much!! Seems am not using it correctly.

Below is the piece of code, can someone please assist:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamodb = new doc.DynamoDB();

var params = {    
TableName : 'abcmsg',
ProjectionExpression: 'Message',
  Key : { 
   "ind" : "ABC10"
    }
};

var MESSAGE_ID = getmsg();

function getmsg(MESSAGE_ID) {
dynamodb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
             console.log('ERROR: Dynamo Failed:', err);
             getmsg(err);
        } else {
               console.log('Dynamo Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ')); 
               let MESSAGE_ID = data['Item'].Message;
               console.log('data',data['Item'].Message); 
               getmsg(MESSAGE_ID);        
        }
});


console.log('MESSAGE_ID',MESSAGE_ID); //print the correct value 'ABCD'

var sns = new AWS.SNS({
      region:'eu-west-1',
      maxRetries: 0

});

sns.publish({
Message: MESSAGE_ID,
Subject:"Test Message",
TopicArn:"arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:0123456789012:Lambda"
}, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
console.log(err.stack);
return;
}
console.log('push sent');
});

callback(null,{ "statusCode": 200 });
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

}

};
```

Logs:-----

2018-01-02T10:14:55.005Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    Dynamo Success: {
  "Item": {
    "Message": "ABCD"
  }
}
2018-01-02T10:14:55.005Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    data ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.006Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    MESSAGE_ID ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.028Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    push sent
2018-01-02T10:14:55.086Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    Dynamo Success: {
  "Item": {
    "Message": "ABCD"
  }
}
2018-01-02T10:14:55.105Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    data ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.106Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    MESSAGE_ID ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.127Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    push sent
2018-01-02T10:14:55.167Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    Dynamo Success: {
  "Item": {
    "Message": "ABCD"
  }
}
2018-01-02T10:14:55.185Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    data ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.186Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    MESSAGE_ID ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.226Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    push sent
2018-01-02T10:14:55.253Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    Dynamo Success: {
  "Item": {
    "Message": "ABCD"
  }
}
2018-01-02T10:14:55.265Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    data ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.285Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    MESSAGE_ID ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.306Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    push sent
2018-01-02T10:14:55.345Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    Dynamo Success: {
  "Item": {
    "Message": "ABCD"
  }
}
2018-01-02T10:14:55.365Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    data ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.366Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    MESSAGE_ID ABCD
2018-01-02T10:14:55.386Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    push sent
2018-01-02T10:14:55.406Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    push sent
2018-01-02T10:14:55.445Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    Dynamo Success: {
  "Item": {
    "Message": "ABCD"
  }
}
2018-01-02T10:14:55.445Z    c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7    data ABCD
END RequestId: c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7
REPORT RequestId: c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7  Duration: 10010.15 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 44 MB
2018-01-02T10:14:55.463Z c18d142e-efa5-11e7-8671-7f3af13c58c7 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get the item with key value `"ind" : "ABC10"` and notify using SNS.

In that case, the `sns.publish` should be called on successful of `getItem` i.e. instead of `getmsg(MESSAGE_ID)`, the `sns publish function` should be called (i.e. you need to create one to publish the message) or `sns publish code block` should be executed (i.e. just copy and paste the sns publish code block inside the getItem else part).

I don't understand why you are calling the getmsg(err) (i.e. during error on getItem) or getmsg(MESSAGE_ID) (i.e. on success of getItem)? I think this is **not** correct. It is basically calling the getItem in a loop which causes time out error.

Comment: Thank you!! It helped. I made some changes and seemed to working fine at the moment. Thanks again!!